# Shell command SET -X mean in script

Tags: bash, sh

So I have a file **deploy.sh**, and it has the shell script. Since I know about it, I have a little confusion, that is what does that `set -x` actually means.

After running the file I have observed that the command written after it in the file gets mentioned in the terminal with a **+** sign.

Like if I have this,

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

ng build
```

So the output mentions `+ng build`, and when I comment the `set -x` from the file, everything executes, but the later commands does not show up in the terminal.

I have researched about it, but specifically couldn't find the real meaning and work of this particular command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can read the `bash` [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) for `set`:

> -x
>
> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select
>   commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or
>   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
>   executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant
>   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

So it does exactly what you described.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to find but this is from the bash man page:

```
   set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...]
          Without options, the name and value of each shell  variable  are
          displayed in a format that can be reused as input for setting or
          resetting the currently-set variables.  Read-only variables can‐
          not  be  reset.  In posix mode, only shell variables are listed.
          The output is sorted according  to  the  current  locale.   When
          options  are specified, they set or unset shell attributes.  Any
          arguments remaining after option processing are treated as  val‐
          ues for the positional parameters and are assigned, in order, to
          $1, $2, ...  $n.  Options,  if  specified,  have  the  following
          meanings:
          [...]
          -x      After expanding each simple command, for  command,  case
                  command, select command, or arithmetic for command, dis‐
                  play the expanded value of PS4, followed by the  command
                  and its expanded arguments or associated word list.
```

So basically it's a debug option.  It does not only execute all the commands but also prints them before it executes them (to stderr).

Comment: I read that in the man page but it's not clear to me if -x echoes the commands or if +x echoes the commands. That is to me. YMMV. Maybe you have to know what PS4 does. The way it reads, it says -x will display stuff which isn't the case.